# Mac m1, rtree 0.9.7, spatialindex 1.9.3, symbol not found

Tags: python, django, spatial-index, r-tree

```
() isikkaplan@iamhere# python3 manage.py loadfixtures -s=testing fixture fixtures/knock/0_ct.json -v3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/isikkaplan/Desktop/code/---/-/--/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/isikkaplan/Desktop/code/---/-/--/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alphashape/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .alphashape import alphashape
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alphashape/alphashape.py", line 15, in <module>
    import geopandas
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py", line 126, in <module>
    default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py", line 112, in _default_use_pygeos
    import geopandas._compat as compat
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_compat.py", line 202, in <module>
    import rtree  # noqa
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rtree/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .index import Rtree, Index  # noqa
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rtree/index.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rtree/core.py", line 77, in <module>
    rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 395, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/--/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 400, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, Error_GetLastErrorNum): symbol not found
```

Almost all of the answers online leads to installing spatialindex which I already have and I have no idea how can I fix this.

Comment: It's the built in command from a framework, there is no other code. The desired behavior is that it doesn't error and the shortest code to reproduce is any geodjango fixture, and someone who knows django and geodjango can easily tell that I'm trying to load some fixtures and the library that's broken is also inside the traceback. I don't know what else should be included, there is nothing else to include as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a conda environment like I am, which is basically a necessity if you are on an m1 and not using docker, then you need to install the system libraries for the current environment via conda also.

```
conda install -c conda-forge libspatialindex
```